# how to call standard leftclick selection in edit mode from bpy.ops

Tags: python, scripting

### tldr:

`editmode` has a workspace modal tool that stops from the other selection tools from being used to expand on the `editmode` ops behaviour, meaning i need a substitute for the `LEFT_MOUSE` click selection

### Goal:

currently working with a modal operator that is meant to replace the entire set of mesh tools 
everything is fine up until the selection operator for `LEFT_MOUSE` when in `"EDIT_MESH"` mode

everything works perfectly fine, including all `bpy.ops.mesh.select...`, but i was not able to find a replacement for the standard `LEFT_MOUSE`

`bpy.ops.view3d.select()` does nothing within `editmode`  it seems, so i don't know what operator should i call

### Reason:

i need permanent settings that the user can choose to swap to, meaning: using the `loop_select`as an example, in the full code within the modal it blocks input from `LEFT_MOUSE` and uses that operator instead with a user-chosen subset of options for extending, toggling etc

i need the same as explained above as i need to be able to control the `LEFT_MOUSE` behaviour from within the modal like the code below:

````py
        leftclick_mode = context.scene.alx_tool_unlocked_modeling_properties.leftclick_mode
        leftclick_selection_mode = context.scene.alx_tool_unlocked_modeling_properties.leftclick_selection_mode

        if (event.type == "LEFTMOUSE") and (event.ctrl == False):
            if (context.mode == "EDIT_MESH"):
                override_window = context.window
                override_screen = override_window.screen
                override_area = [area for area in override_screen.areas if area.type == "VIEW_3D"]
                override_region = [region for region in override_area[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']
                
                bExtend = True if (leftclick_selection_mode == "EXTEND") else False
                
                with context.temp_override(window=override_window, area=override_area[0], region=override_region[0]):
                    if (leftclick_mode == "NONE"):
                        bpy.ops.view3d.select()

                    elif (leftclick_mode == "LOOP_SELECTION"):
                        bpy.ops.mesh.loop_select("INVOKE_DEFAULT", extend=bExtend, deselect=False, toggle=False, ring=False)
            return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function i was looking for is: `bpy.ops.view3d.select("INVOKE_DEFAULT")`
`"INVOKE_DEFAULT"` is necessary for the operator to be called, without it the operator simply won't run

additionally an example for my `editmode` use case that overrides context:

```
if (context.mode == "EDIT_MESH"):
    override_window = context.window
    override_screen = override_window.screen
    override_area = [area for area in override_screen.areas if area.type == "VIEW_3D"]
    override_region = [region for region in override_area[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']

    with context.temp_override(window=override_window, area=override_area[0], region=override_region[0]):
        bpy.ops.view3d.select("INVOKE_DEFAULT", extend=False, deselect=False)
```